# Correct ImageFormat for image/x-xbitmap mime type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What is the correct `ImageFormat` for `X11 bitmap` (`.xbm` / `image/x-xbitmap`) files?

Is it `ImageFormat.Bmp` or `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`?

Comment: XBM format is a *descriptor*. Each byte's bits represent a *state*: 0 = White, 1 = Black (or whatever color you decide to use). Maybe `Icon` is closer. Or a `Format1bppIndexed` Bitmap. But it's not supported, directly. [ImageMagick .Net](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) still does. If you're referring to this [ImageFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat), that is.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Image Format. I am attempting to get the correct file extension for a given ImageFormat (pulled from the base64 image) and this is apparently something I need to support :-(

Comment: There's no native support for this image format (it's a very old format). It's like a header file, where the `Width` and `Height` of the Bitmap are specified as variables and the Pixels states are stored in a byte array. You can read the bits values of each byte and use `SetPixel()` in a loop (or `Image.LockBits()`) to set the color of each pixel. Or use the library a mentioned before.